# How do layout_weight makes widgets disappear?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I have LinearLayouts nested in a "Master Layout" with their width set to `fill_parent` and height to `0dp`.

The Master has a weight sum of 100 and a vertical orientation, and I have the nested layouts with their respective weights. The goal is to split the vertical space, but they all disappear. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the XML, I have only applied the `weight/layouts` to the top few.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:weightSum="100">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout03"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="20" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/terranlogo1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/terranlogo" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/protosslogo1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/protosslogo" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/zerglogo1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/zerglogo" />
</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout04"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/ck_t1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/ck_p1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/ck_z1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />
 </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout05"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/terranlogo2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/terranlogo" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/protosslogo2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/protosslogo" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/zerglogo2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/zerglogo" />
 </LinearLayout>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/ck_t2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/ck_p2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/ck_z2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Choose your opponets race(s) and your race(s)"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Game Length"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/s_answertime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Mistakes Allowed"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Answer Time"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/s_mistakenumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />


<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/s_gametime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post the layout file.

Comment: They can do if you dont use it properly yes.

Comment: This layout file will not even compile, as you never close the original `LinearLayout` element.

Comment: Whoops, that was deleted when entering in the code. It is actually there in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way how to split available space evenly

```
<LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Text1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1.0">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Text2"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Text3"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```